# PHP-APC Installation

Tags: php, fastcgi, php-fpm, mod-fcgid, alternative-php-cache

Trying to get my head around the way to install `APC` cache on PHP 5.3.13. That's a VPS with apache, configured preferably through whm/cpanel (although not only).

I read a bunch of articles where it was suggested to use `FastCGI` with APC, as `suPHP` doens't do well with opcode caching, and `fcgid_module` doesn't do it right for APC either. Noted that fcgid_module is a newer package than FastCGI and that's what whm/cpanel installs for you but ok, that can be solved I guess. Then I'm reading that `php-fpm` is a much better alternative to manage the php processes, especially for APC.

Ok. Then I realised that `php-fpm` is included in php core since 5.3 and got confused. Does that mean I don't have to use `FastCGI/fcgid_module` (and what should I use instead of them - mod_php or cgi?)? Or does that mean that I still need to get the older `FastCGI` module, and configure it to use one process per user (or just one process?)? Or would `fcgid_module` work as well?

And how bad would it be just to go with mod_php/APC to avoid troubles of installing php-fpm and FastCGI (whm/cpanel doesn't support neither) given than Varnish would serve most of the static content anyway - no php process need to be created for static content.

Any examples of their FastCGI/fcgid_module/php-fpm/APC configurations would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: There's about a dozen questions in there, each of which require a *lot* of information from you in order to answer.  You might consider asking several separate questions.

Comment: Basically my question is what are the best ways to go about installing APC on PHP5.3? Ideally a way without hacking into whm/cpanel too much.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just go with DSO as a PHP Handler + Mod_Ruid2 + APC? It's a great configuration (also for high traffic sites) and it can be installed using EasyApache in WHM.

Comment: that's what I did in the end but unfortunately didn't know about mod_ruid2 at the time and have to run symfony2 scripts under 'nobody'